# Troubleshooting nested CollectionViews in .NET Maui and changing DataType

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, maui-collectionview

.net Maui CollectionViews I am trying to nest my views and set my DataType value to the respective ObservableCollections that have my objects I need to pull data from to display. Unfortunately I can't seem to get my DataType="model:Relapse" to change to anything else after it is set breaking my ability to have any other CollectionViews contained within.

IDE: Visual Studio 2022
PlatformDetails: net7.0-android33.0

Sample of XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding RelapseDiaryEntries}" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
                    <CollectionView.Header>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="Entries:" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,10" Padding="0" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </CollectionView.Header>
                    <CollectionView.EmptyView>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
                            <Label Text="Add a Relapse Diary Entry to get started!"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </CollectionView.EmptyView>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:RelapseDiaryViewModel">
                            <ContentView Padding="0" Margin="0">
                                <Frame Margin="0" Padding="0,10">
                                    <toolkit:Expander>
                                        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,10,*" Margin="0" Padding="0" x:DataType="model:Relapse" >
                                                <Label Text="{Binding DateAndTime}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5" Padding="0" FontSize="16"/>
                                                <Label Text="|" FontSize="Title" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0,0,0,5" Margin="0" />
                                                <Label  Text="{Binding Location}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="5" Padding="0" FontSize="16"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                        <StackLayout HeightRequest="300" x:DataType="{x:Null}">
                                            <Frame Padding="0" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                                <StackLayout x:DataType="viewmodel:RelapseDiaryViewModel" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TriggersForUser}" HeightRequest="135" Background="black" Margin="0" Padding="0">
                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Trigger">
                                                            <Grid x:Name="Triggers" Margin="5" RowDefinitions="*,*" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                                                                <Label Text="Triggers:" TextColor="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                                                <Frame Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" BackgroundColor="Pink">
                                                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
                                                                        <toolkit:Expander>
                                                                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                                                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                                                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                                        </toolkit:Expander>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Frame>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Frame>
                                            <Frame Padding="0" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="Black">
                                                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding SymptomsForUser}" HeightRequest="135" Background="black" Margin="3">
                                                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Symptom">
                                                            <Grid x:Name="Symptoms" Margin="5" RowDefinitions="*,*">
                                                                <Label Text="Symptoms:" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="AliceBlue"/>
                                                                <Frame BorderColor="White" Grid.Row="1">
                                                                    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*">
                                                                        <toolkit:Expander>
                                                                            <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                                                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Row="0" TextColor="White"/>
                                                                            </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                                                                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" Grid.Row="1" TextColor="White"/>
                                                                        </toolkit:Expander>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                </Frame>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </toolkit:Expander>
                                </Frame>
                            </ContentView>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

Sample of my ViewModel

```
ObservableCollection<Relapse> _relapseDiaryEntries = new ObservableCollection<Relapse>();
        public ObservableCollection<Relapse> RelapseDiaryEntries
        {
            get { return _relapseDiaryEntries; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _relapseDiaryEntries, value); }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Model.Trigger> _triggersForUser = new ObservableCollection<Model.Trigger>();
        public ObservableCollection<Model.Trigger> TriggersForUser
        {
            get { return _triggersForUser; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _triggersForUser, value); }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Symptom> _symptomsForUser = new ObservableCollection<Symptom>();
        public ObservableCollection<Symptom> SymptomsForUser
        {
            get { return _symptomsForUser; } 
            set { SetProperty(ref _symptomsForUser, value); }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task Reload()
        {
            PageTitle = "Relapse Diary";
            TheUser = ThisUser;
            RelapseDiaryEntries.Clear();
            await Init();
        }

        public async Task Init()
        {
            await LoadRelapses(TheUser.UserId);
        }

        private async Task LoadRelapses(int UserId)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Relapse> _allRelapses = await RelapseCalls.GetRelapsesAsync();
            ObservableCollection<Model.Trigger> _triggersAll = await TriggerCalls.GetTriggersAsync();
            ObservableCollection<Symptom> _symptomsAll = await SymptomCalls.GetSymptomsAsync();

            foreach (Relapse r in _allRelapses)
            {
                if (r.UserId == UserId)
                {
                    RelapseDiaryEntries.Add(r);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                foreach (Relapse r in RelapseDiaryEntries)
                {
                    foreach (Model.Trigger t in _triggersAll)
                    {
                        if (r.TriggerCollectionId == t.TriggerCollectionId)
                        {
                            TriggersForUser.Add(t);
                        }
                    }
                    foreach (Symptom s in _symptomsAll)
                    {
                        if (r.SymptomCollectionId == s.SymptomCollectionId)
                        {
                            SymptomsForUser.Add(s);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

This gives me the Error:
'TriggersForUser' property not found on 'WGU_Capstone_C868.Model.Relapse', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.StackLayout.ItemsSource' once compiled and running.

What I am trying to accomplish is a list of expandable items that then show a list of related items, that then expand to show a text description of those items.

I am doing MVVM and have tried a number of work arounds found online such as using a StackView inside a CollectionView with different DataTemplates set with the correct DataType for the data they hold.

Some ideas I have about what is going on is maybe the compiler is only seeing the first DataType and this is a compiler bug? Or after searching and reding all the documentation and even selling my soul to ChatGPT to find a solution I have repeatedly missunderstood how DataType works? Here is a sample of one of my attemps and the Error I am getting trying to bind objects.

Comment: In Maui, properties are found via `BindingContext`, not `x:DataType`. The type is useful to xaml compilation, but isn't enough information to find the properties. Its like the difference between a class, and an instance of that class. Just knowing something is an elephant doesn't find the actual elephant being referred to. Anyway, collections have an `ItemsSource` that sets the `BindingContext` to each item. **If property isn't found,** then something is wrong with the type of items in ItemsSource collection, vs. the `Binding` `Path`.

Comment: Looks like error message mentions `TriggersForUser` property on `Model.Relapse`. I don't see definition of `Relapse` class; please add it to question.

Comment: DataModel Type of Trigger Object, is not contained in the DataModel Type of Relapse Object. I need it to look for the Type of Trigger in the List of TriggersForUser to bind the Title and Description props of a Trigger AFTER I have populated my data from the list of Relapse objects. The Relapse objects in the ObservableCollection populate their data without any issues. It is anything AFTER that, which still looks for a type of Relapse no matter how I try to redeclare the type to a different model... or even a null DataModel x:Null which were ideas taken from the Maui Documentation directly.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, Yes BindingContext is the correct thing for the props, The problem is that it is looking for the wrong DataType first before grabbing properties. Since the prop isn't a part of that model it has locked it's sights on, it ignores my Path for the Prop and tells me that it isn't an actual thing. Other things I have tried are Relative Bindings, but admittedly the documentation wasn't the most specific or I may not have understood it fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Since the prop isn't a part of that model it has locked it's sights on, it ignores my Path for the Prop and tells me that it isn't an actual thing."

Because you haven't given it enough information to find the start of the Path.

NOTE: If having trouble getting these to work, temporarily remove ALL `x:DataType` statements from the XAML file. They help Intellisense, and runtime-performance, but if you use ANY in a file, then you have to correctly set them at ALL nested places. (Hopefully this eventually won't be needed; there is no valid reason for XAML compiler to think that an ItemTemplate defaults to the same x:DataType as the containing collection. That makes no logical sense.) Get it to work without any x:DataType. (There may be Intellisense errors; disregard those, run it and see if there are any runtime errors.) Get it to work, then add them back in, if you want. (I often omit them.)

I'll call your ViewModel class `MyViewModel` (I don't see a name for it in your question).

Setting `x:DataType="MyViewModel"` does not tell Maui *how to find the current instance of MyViewModel*. I'll call the current page class `MyPage`. MyPage's `BindingContext` is the desired `MyViewModel` instance.

Here are several ways to reach the desired Path.

---

1. Give page an `x:Name`, and use a path from that:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    x:Name="thisPage"
    Class="MyPage">
    ...
      BindableLayout.ItemsSource=
        "{Binding VM.TriggersForUser, Source={x:Reference thisPage}}"
```

This looks at `x:Name`s in the page's XAML. It finds that MyPage is named `thisPage`.

Where MyPage code-behind contains property VM (to get the correct type automatically):

```cs
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public MyViewModel VM => (MyViewModel)BindingContext;
}
```

---

2. Search ancestors for type MyPage:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyMauiApp"   <-- replace with namespace that contains MyPage class.
    Class="MyPage">

      BindableLayout.ItemsSource=
        "{Binding VM.TriggersForUser, Source={RelativeReference 
          AncestorType={x:Type local:MyPage}}}"
```

This searches up the XAML hierarchy. When it reaches MyPage, that is a matching type, so it starts the path there.

Again, this relies on a code-behind property `VM`.

---

3. Search type that is a BindingContext of some ancestor:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
    xmlns:myvms="clr-namespace:MyMauiApp"   <-- namespace containing MyViewModel class.
    Class="MyPage">

      BindableLayout.ItemsSource=
        "{Binding TriggersForUser, Source={RelativeReference 
          AncestorType={x:Type myvms:MyViewModel}}}"
```

This searches up the XAML hierarchy. When it reaches MyPage, it checks type of `BindingContext`, and sees that it matches `MyViewModel`.

I've never done it this way -- referring directly to a ViewModel instead of to a UI class such as MyPage -- but I've seen others who have, so I assume it works now.